# On the principal eigenvector of an elliptic operator

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Suppose I have an open domain $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and an elliptic operator $L$ acting on all square-integrable $C^2$ functions $\rho:U\to \mathbb{R}$ which converge to zero at $\partial U$:
\begin{equation}
L\rho = -\nabla \cdot \left(f\nabla \rho\right)
\end{equation}
where $f$ is some positive function. Under what circumstances can $f$ and the principal eigenvector $\rho^+$ of $L$ have the same level-surfaces? i.e.
\begin{equation}
\nabla \rho^+ = g \nabla f
\end{equation}
for some function $g$.

Can this only occur whenever $U$ is a ball centered on some point $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ while $f$ is invariant under rotations around this point?

This question is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790088/static-self-gravitating-gas-spherically-symmetric